# How do I pass a feature file itself as a variable?

Tags: karate

I am trying to do something like this:
sample_generic.feature

```
Scenario:
    * def result = call read('#(feature)') headers
```

And i have another feature file like this:
sample_caller.feature

```
Scenario:
   * def result = call read('sample_generic.feature') {feature: 'classpath:common/example.feature'}
```

When I try to do this, I am getting error:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException:
/****/test-suite/src/test/java/example/common/#(feature) (No such file or directory)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFeatureCall(Script.java:1647)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.call(Script.java:1579)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:228)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:170)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:598)
  at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:524)
  at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:305)
  at ✽.* def result = call read('classpath:common/sample_generic.feature') {feature: 'example.feature'}(/*****/test-suite/src/test/java/example/common/example.feature:12)
```

Any idea on whether this way of dynamically calling feature file itself is supported by karate?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.
I got it working.
Instead of '#(feature)', if we pass just feature, it picks up fine.

```
Scenario:
    * def result = call read(feature) headers
```

This worked!

Comment: can you mark your own answer as accepted ? I like to see all `karate` questions answered :)